# Azure devops - ansible azure rm issue

Tags: azure-devops, ansible, azure-rm

I have an issue with running the pipeline, i'm trying to run ansible using the dynamic inventory azure_rm

does anyone has any idea how to fix this?

i get several message errors like the one below :

```
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse
/home/vsts/work/1/s/ansible/inventory/myazure_rm.yml with auto plugin: name
'azure_cloud' is not defined
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse
/home/vsts/work/1/s/ansible/inventory/myazure_rm.yml with yaml plugin: Plugin
configuration YAML file, not YAML inventory
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse
/home/vsts/work/1/s/ansible/inventory/myazure_rm.yml with ini plugin: Invalid
host pattern 'plugin:' supplied, ending in ':' is not allowed, this character
is reserved to provide a port.
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /home/vsts/work/1/s/ansible/inventory/myazure_rm.yml
as an inventory source
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that
the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
```

it is pretty much a simple inventory:

```
plugin: azure_rm
include_vm_resource_groups:
  - rg-test
auth_source: auto
fail_on_template_errors: False
location: "france central"
```

Comment: that the name myazure_rm.yml

Comment: See https://github.com/ansible-collections/azure/issues/661. Which version of python is your ansible controller using ?

Comment: here the ansible and python version ansible [core 2.12.1]
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)

Comment: Just for confirmation: did you install the collection and all python prereqs?

Comment: i did thru this command  pip install ansible[azure]
unless i miss something out

Comment: This is not the documented way to install the collection (although it might work). The documentation recommends to first check if the collection is installed by issuing `ansible-galaxy collection list` and inspect the output, then issue `ansible-galaxy collection install azure.azcollection` in case it is not. See top page notes in https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/azure/azcollection/azure_rm_inventory.html#ansible-collections-azure-azcollection-azure-rm-inventory

Comment: i follow these instruction https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_azure.html

Comment: found it was due to the ansible version for the azure rm module.